# code will generate compile error

Tags: c#

The following code will generate a compiler error.

```
string GetAgePhrase(int age) 
   {
     if (age > 50) return "Naresh";
     if (age > 30) return "Ravi";
     if (age > 10) return "Nagendra";
     if (age > 9) return "Jagan";
     if (age > 2) return "Raja";
   }
```

Which of the following statements, inserted as the last line of the 
function, would solve the problem?

Comment: What "following statements" do you mean? please clarify

Comment: This is not the place to get your multiple choice homework or exam questions answered. Take the code, try to compile it, read the error message, and see what fixes it yourself.

Comment: You probably shouldn't hard code these value.  A database table or even entries in your config file would be a better way to do this.  That way you avoid problems with inevitable changes when your users want to differentiate people over 70, or divide the space between 30 and 50 into a 30/40 and 40/50 split, or change one of the names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this code is that not all paths of the code return a value... i.e. what if age is 0? You can fix this by adding after the last if statement `return null` this way if none of the conditions are met it will always have a return value.

Answer (score 0):

Your method doesn't always return a value, so just a default return after all the if statements.

```
   string GetAgePhrase(int age) 
   {
     if (age > 50) return "Naresh";
     if (age > 30) return "Ravi";
     if (age > 10) return "Nagendra";
     if (age > 9) return "Jagan";
     if (age > 2) return "Raja";

     return null;
   }
```

Comment: Yes it will return the default values.